On an improper integral with an integrand that exhibits odd symmetry
Consider the function $f(x) = \sin \left( \dfrac{1}{x^{2n+1}} \right)$ when $x \neq 0$ and define $f(0)=0$. It is evident that $f'(0)$ is nonexistent. Suppose we are trying to calculate
$$ \int\limits_{-a}^a f(x) d x $$
We see $f$ is odd, so the integral is $0$. However, $f$ has a discontinuity at $0$. How do we give a more rigorous proof that the integral is indeed 0?

The integral is the sum of two (convergent) improper  integrals $\int_0^af $ and $\int_{-a}^0 f$ with singularity at $0.$ By definition $$\int\limits_0^af=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{\varepsilon}^af,\quad  \int\limits_{-a}^0f=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-a}^{-\varepsilon}f$$ When $f$ is odd $$ \int_{\varepsilon}^af + \int_{-a}^{-\varepsilon}f= 0$$ Taking the limit when $\varepsilon\to 0^+$ gives  $$ \int_{0}^af + \int_{-a}^{0}f= 0$$
